# What actions are taken to improve the efficiency of modern high-efficiency induction motor

Tags: motor, induction-motor, efficiency

What actions are taken to improve the efficiency of modern high-efficiency induction
motors?

Comment: I think this question is about concepts for improving the efficiency of today's typical high-efficiency IM designs. As such I don't think this question if overly broad or otherwise off-topic. I suggest that the question should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

A modern high-efficiency induction motor will be about as efficient as it can be without increasing the manufacturing cost to an extent that would not be very attractive under most circumstances.

The design change that would probably have the biggest impact would be to use copper rotor bars and end rings rather than aluminum. That is quite costly, but it is a design feature used in Tesla electric car motors.

The liquid cooling used by Tesla may not increase the efficiency very much since power is required to circulate the coolant. Making the motor physically larger and using a more effective radiating structure on the outside would increase the efficiency by reducing the power required to move air through or across the surface of a standard motor.

If a larger stator is used for a given torque rating, the size of the copper windings could be increased to reduce losses.

More expensive bearings would provide some reduction in the already quite small bearing friction losses. More expensive bearings may be required for the heavier copper rotor.

There may be some opportunity to reduce the iron losses, but that is probably quite limited.

Comment: I'd add using a variable frequency drive. That may be obvious to anyone in the topic but as most induction motors are still the capacitor-only type, that's the single most important thing to increase energy efficiency (if you had variable speeds and/or many on/off cycles).

Comment: I was not considering single-phase induction motors as being "modern high-efficiency induction motors." The most significant improvement to a single-phase motor is to use something else such as a 3-phase induction motor, a 3-phase IM with a 1-ph input VFD or a permanent magnet motor. A VFD does not improve the efficiency of a 3-phase motor, but it may improve the efficiency of a process.

Comment: It does if the motor has been speed-controlled by changing voltage and/or series resistors and/or resistive cage, because all these methods increase slip (and so, increase rotor losses) for the sake of having some "speed control".

Comment: I agree, but I don't think that is at all what is being asked about.

Comment: You are into the topic as I am, but the question seemed like one a teacher would ask his students.

Answer (score 0):

Different motor mfrs use different combinations of techniques, but among those are:
 1. Reduce the air gap, which means higher precision bearings 
 2. Reduce the friction via better bearings (part of the above as well)
 3. Reduce the copper losses in the stator by reducing resistance in the coils though different geometries for the slots and larger or more conductors (results in higher inrush)
 4. Aluminum rotor bars
 5. Reduce magnetic (eddy current) losses by using premium quality
    grain oriented silicon steel in the laminations of the stator / rotor cores,
    increasing the core length and using thinner laminations

Comment: Are you interpreting the question as how can today's high efficiency designs be improved or how have today's typical high efficiency designs been improved over prior designs? Do you believe there are significant further improvements feasible in the area of iron loss and smaller air gaps?

Comment: I was assuming the OP wanted to know how we got there, i.e. how is an energy efficient induction motor different from an older version. I doubt there are any further meaningful gains to be made in the actual induction motor design. Small gains, maybe. But we went from the 70-80% eff range into the high 90s, so we will not see that kind of incremental gain again.